# Error in python while converting string to datetime with timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

Code:

```
pd.to_datetime(dataset['startdate'] ,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z")
```

I got following error

```
ValueError: time data '2020-02-25 14:56:05+01' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z' (match)
```

help much appreciate.

Comment: just use `pd.to_datetime(dataset['startdate'] )`, you don't need to provide the formatting directive explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Times series data contains +01 and +02 as well due to daylight saving. That was causing an error. Should be using %z as well

Answer (score 1):

Your format has a `%Z` (uppercase) at the end, which according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) timezone name (like GMT, PSD …). You probably want to use `%z` (lowercase) which is UTC offset (like ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]]). However not sure if that would work `+01`, you might need `+0100`.